# Sample code of google chart tools that call JSON service

Tags: json, charts

Can someone send me correct code that can create interactive chart by calling JSON API URL ?

Example:  chart based on JSON API in url

http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

In google site there is a sample in https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

but the below shows nothing (I replaced original JSON PHP file location with my URL)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo ",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the JSON returned from the URL that you gave (http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo), it looks like it doesn't conform to the [DataTable JSON format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam).

From https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_preparing_data:

> All charts require data. Google Chart Tools charts require data to be
>   wrapped in a JavaScript class called google.visualization.DataTable.
>   This class is defined in the Google Visualization library that you
>   loaded previously.   A DataTable is a two-dimensional table with rows
>   and columns, where each column has a datatype, an optional ID, and an
>   optional label.

If you look at the sample JSON data that they provide, you'll see that it conforms to the DataTable format:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

Comment: thanks, how can I convert it ?  Is there any other BI, BAM or chart tool that allow me to show dashboards without coding but by getting data from my JSON web service ?